# How to modify jsonapi response?

Tags: 8

Hello Drupal community.

I have a “Product” content type with field_alert_date field.
The field date type is “Date only” so when I get jsonapi response
by accessing jsonapi/node/product I have the following output for this field:

```
"field_alert_date":"2020-02-22"
```

However, this response will be used by another program
and that program requires data in the following format:

```
"field_alert_date":"2020-02-22 0:00:00”
```

So I need to modify the jsonapi output to add “0:00:00” (or another time) without changing the field data type.
The program is not developed by me so I cannot change this requirement. 
I have to do something with the output of the jsonapi.

Could you please tell me if it is possible and how it can be implemented?

Answer (score 4):

You can change the JSON output of a date field by implementing a custom Normalizer for date fields in a custom module. I got it to work using the following code. This is a bit of a hatchet job, so you'll want to clean up and stuff, but otherwise it should do the job:

/src/Normalizer/DateTimeCustomNormalizer.php:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_date_serializer\Normalizer;

use Drupal\serialization\Normalizer\DateTimeIso8601Normalizer;

/**
 * @internal
 */
class DateTimeCustomNormalizer extends DateTimeIso8601Normalizer {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected $allowedFormats = [
    'RFC 3339' => \DateTime::RFC3339,
    'ISO 8601' => \DateTime::ISO8601,
    // used to be 'Y-m-d', so you can use any PHP date format you want
    // I just set it to this because it was easy to test
    'date-only' => \DateTime::ISO8601, 
  ];
}
```

And /custom_date_serializer.services.yml:

```
services:
  custom_date_serializer.normalizer.datetimecustom:
    class: \Drupal\custom_date_serializer\Normalizer\DateTimeCustomNormalizer
    arguments: ['@config.factory']
    tags:
      # Priority must be higher than other datetime normalizers.
      - { name: normalizer, priority: 40 }
```

And you'll need an info.yml obviously.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it.